# Where to implement python classes in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm learning `Django` on my own and I can't seem to get a clue of where I implement a regular Python class. What I mean is, I don't know where do the Python classes I write go. Like they go in a separate file and then are imported to the `views.py` or are the classes implemented inside the `views.py` file?

Example I want to implement a `Class Alphabet`, should I do this in a separate file inside the module or just implement the functions inside the `views.py` file?

Comment: Put it anywhere django will find it.  I often have a utils module for general purpose utilities.

Comment: Thank you for the answers! But if I put it in a separate file and then import it, how do I print the attributes in a HTML template? I know that through the functions in the views.py I must return the request and template name. Yet I can't seem to "pass" my attributes to the template page.

Comment: `return render_to_response('my_page.html', template_values_dict, ...)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't know where do the Python classes I write go. Like they go in
>   a separate file and then are imported to the views.py.
>   Example I want to implement a Class Alphabet.

It's just a matter of getting your import statement correct:

```
django_proj1/
   django_proj1/
   myapp/
      myclasses.py
      views.py
```

Then in your view:

```
#myapp/views.py:
from myapp.myclasses import Alphabet
```

Or, you could do it like this:

```
django_proj1/
   django_proj1/
      myclasses.py
   myapp/
      views.py
```

And in your view:

```
#myapp/views.py:
from django_proj1.myclasses import Alphabet
```

**Response to comment:**

> And after I successfully imported my class, how do I pass the
>   attributes to an HTML template?

The following is straight from the official [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something).

**myapp/views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

from myapp.myclasses import Alphabet  #<*** Import your class.
from django.template import RequestContext, loader  #<*** Import stuff for the template.

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    alph = Alphabet()
    result = alph.change('hello')  #Your class produces some result here.

    template = loader.get_template("myapp/index.html")
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'x' : result   #<*** Make a variable named x available in your template.
    })

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

The `directory structure` looks like this:

```
django_proj1/
   django_proj1/
   myapp/
      myclasses.py
      views.py
      templates/  <***Create this directory 
          myapp/  <***Create this directory
             index.html  <***Create this file
```

**myapp/templates/myapp/index.html**:

```
{% if x %}
<div>The result you requested was: {{x}}</div>
{% else %}
<div>Sorry, couldn't get the result.</div>
{% endif %}
```

**myapp/myclasses.py**:

```
class Alphabet:
    def change(self, word):
        return word + 'Z'
```

**Start the server**:

```
.../my_django_projects/django_proj1$ python manage.py runserver
```

**url in your browser**:

```
http://localhost:8000/myapp/
```

You should see:

> The result you requested was: helloZ

If you comment out the following line in `myapp/views.py`:

```
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        #'x' : result   #<*** Make a variable named x available in your template.
    })
```

Then the template will send the `else` portion of `index.html` to the browser:

> Sorry, couldn't get the result.

**django_proj1/django_proj1/urls.py**:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'dj1.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),

)
```

**django_proj1/myapp/urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Comment: And after I successfully imported my class, how do I pass the attributes to an HTML template? Do I return an object of the class created in the views.py with the render() or render_to_response?

Comment: Check my answer for an idea of how to do this

Comment: @Silvestrini, See my response at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Django is just Python at the end of the day.

You can create new modules anywhere in your project, and import them into your views, models, urls, etc. This is often how you'd organize general utils (utils.py).

You can deliver data to your views in a few ways, for instance:

```
from your_module import some_object

class MyView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'some_template.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['my_data'] = some_object.some_method()
        return context
```

And in `some_template.html`: `{{ my_data }}`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the scope of the Alphabet class. If it is a utility class then I would suggest to put in a utils.py file, for example. But it is perfectly fine to have classes in the views.py file, mainly those dealing with UI processing. Up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Distinct to similar frameworks, you can put your Python code anywhere in your project, provided you can reference them later by their import path (model classes are partially an exception, though):

1. Applications are referenced by their import path (or an `AppConfig` import path). Although there's some magic involving `test.py` and `models.py`, most of the times the import / reference is quite explicit.
2. Views are referenced by `urls.py` files, but imported as regular python import path.
3. Middlewares are referenced by strings which denote an import path ending with their class name.
4. Other settings you normally don't configure are also full import paths.

The exception to this explicitness is:

1. models.py, test.py, admin.py : They have special purposes and may not exist, providing:

   1. You will not need any model in your app, and will provide an `AppConfig` (instead of just the app name) in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.
   2. You will not rely on autodiscovery for admin classes in your app.
   3. You don't want to make tests on your app, or will specify a non-default path for your app-specific test command run.
2. templates and static files: your project will rely on per-app loaders for your static files and for your templates files, and ultimately there's a brute-force search in each of your apps: their inner `static/` and `templates/` directories, if exist, are searched for those files.

**Everything else is just normal python code** and, if you need to import them from any view, you just do a normal import sentence for them (since view code is imported with the normal Python import mechanism).